# wait for execute alert(123) after execute registerUser() into onLogin() in JavaScript and React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is my function A :

```
 export function registerUser(mobile) {
    ...
}
```

this is function B :

```
    async function onLogin () {
     await registerUser(global.registerMobile)  
      >>>>>>>>alert(123)
  }
```

now I want to run alert(123) after registerUser function execute 
Please Help Me...

Comment: You have to write the async function registerUser.

Comment: so i should change to export async function registerUser?

Comment: for example, export async function registerUser(mobile) { await fetch ... }

Comment: I cant understand

Comment: how to write { await fetch ... } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example code

```js
export const registerUser = (mobile) => new Promise(resolve => {
  Axios.get('SOME URL').then(res => {
    resolve(res.data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mark your registerUser function async

```
export async function registerUser(mobile) {
    await // do async stuff
}
```

or in case you are using promise, you should return it to be able to await for it in `onLogin`

```
export function registerUser(mobile) {
    return fetch('..register url..', options)
}
```

also read docs for react-native alert https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert

Comment: os I must to change   async function onLogin () {
     await registerUser(global.registerMobile)  
      >>>>>>>>alert(123)
  } ?

Comment: your `onLogin` looks fine, only `alert(123)` has to be changed